# PreparedStatement continues to insert if Error

Tags: java, oracle, insert

I have a little concern with Objet **PreparedStatement** in java to insert in an Oracle database.

Infect I prepare well the model of my INSERT query in the **PreparedStatement** I add well all my parameters with an `addBatch()` for each record I want to insert.

I add several batches to insert a 500 record hits for example.

Until then all of them work well I can insert what I want

On the other hand, in case my **PreparedStatement** generates a **BatchUpdateException** error (for example violation of constraint) on the 500 line that I want to insert it inserts me nothing at all.

I want to the limit remove the record that raises concern (with violation constraint) and insert at least the 499 line that are OK

How can I do that ? if she gives me a track I'd be grateful.

Just for Info I want to insert several lines of a stroke from 500 lines, so the solution to insert line by line does not fit me too much performance level.

Cordially

Comment: See the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()).  In particular: _...a JDBC driver may or may not continue to process the remaining commands..._.  If your driver does not provide support then an approach could be to catch the exception, then try line by line for that batch to isolate the line which has the problem.

Comment: I try this, i got same problem

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is not what you want but oracle has some built in error logic

you have to create an error table 
e.g. if the table is called emp, run this

```
exec dbms_errlog.create_error_log(dml_table_name=>'emp');
```

that will create a table err$_emp that will catch the errors

then you can do something like this below(note the log errors into clause)

the batch will succeed and you will have to check the error table for errors after you run it

```
import java.sql.*;


public class Class1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
        int records = 20;

        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(  
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host/db","scott","tiger");

            String compiledQuery = "INSERT INTO EMP(EMPNO)" +
                    " VALUES" + "(?) LOG ERRORS INTO ERR$_EMP REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED";
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(compiledQuery);

            for(int index = 1; index <= records; index++) {
                preparedStatement.setInt(1, index);
                preparedStatement.addBatch();
            }

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            int[] inserted;

            try {
                inserted = preparedStatement.executeBatch();
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                System.out.println("sql error");
            }
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println("total time taken to insert the batch = " + (end - start) + " ms");
            System.out.println("total time taken = " + (end - start)/records + " s");

            preparedStatement.close();
            connection.commit();
            connection.close();



        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("SQLException information");
            while (ex != null) {
                System.err.println("Error msg: " + ex.getMessage());
                ex = ex.getNextException();
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Error");
        }
    }
}
```